# 429 Too Many Requests with calls to external api, but only when using a specific method

Tags: java, spring, api, exception

Okay, so I'm learning Spring right now and I'm working on a project that calls an external api and does some light processing of the info and returns the result back to my user. The problem is that for the bulk of the methods I've created for this purpose, I have had no issues. My most recent method, which takes a list of ids as argument and returns all employees that match, keeps returning:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests: "{<EOL>    "message": "Too Many Attempts."<EOL>}"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:334) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.example.demo.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.getListEmployeesByIds(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.contoller.EmployeeController.getEmployeesByIdList(EmployeeController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
```

Following the error it leads me to my controller and service methods for the method

contoller:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/employees/list")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDTO>> getEmployeesByIdList(@RequestBody IDS idList) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.employeeService.getListEmployeesByIds(idList.getIds()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

service:

```
    public List<EmployeeDTO> getListEmployeesByIds(int[] ids) {
        //List<Employee> employees = extractEmployeesList();
        EmployeeJSON empJSON = restTemplate.getForObject(EndpointConfig.employeeUrl, EmployeeJSON.class);
        List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(empJSON.getData());
        List<EmployeeDTO> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int id : ids) {
            Optional<Employee> empWithId = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getId() == id).findFirst();
            if(empWithId.isPresent()) {
                responseList.add(new EmployeeDTO(empWithId.get()));
            }
        }
        return responseList;
    }
```

Now what I don't understand, is how are these methods making too many calls? The controller calls service and service makes a single call to the external api (http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees) and then tries to process the result as mentioned above. What is it that I am just not seeing or understanding that would result in "Too many requests". I have made calls to my other methods that work before and after attempts of calling the above with success, until I'm entirely locked out for a short time, so I know its just these methods that are response, or at least that's what it appears to be. Please any advice or suggestions about how to fix this would be very helpful.

Comment: Your code looks like it's only calling the external API once, unless `Employee::getId` is somehow making an external request. If you are very sure that nothing is calling *your* API multiple times, it seems possible that it could be a bug in the external API. Have you attempted calling the external API via CURL, for example, and verifying that the API works at all?

Comment: I haven't tried calling the api using CURL, but the other methods that work all use the same call to the api as the above, just with different processing. I'm not sure how/why but I think something must be calling my api multiple times for this method. I'll keep digging to see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got it working. I have been using postman for testing my api, and the best I can come up with is that is where the problem was. After restarting postman and recreating the request, it was successful. If you found this trying to answer a similar problem, look to your method of executing the request, it might just be the answer.